# Accessing a final variable before constructor exit

Tags: java, compiler-construction

Okay, I've been messing around with the excellent JodaTime library, attempting to get a general-case retail/fiscal (4-5-4) calendar implemented.  I've already found the specific case for my company, but the general cases (mostly in determining start-of-year, and leap years) is killer; for instance, there's a set of dates whereby two fiscal years (364 days long, normally) will start during 1 ISO year.

In the process of determining year-start rules, I ended up with an abstract class and a couple of concrete classes for determining year starts, based on which side of the ISO leap-day they fall.

(pared-down) abstract class:

```
private static abstract class SimpleFiscalYearEndPattern implements FiscalYearEndPattern {

    protected final int leapYearCountOffset;
    protected final int doomsdayOffset;

    private final int startingDayOfWeek;
    private final int yearOffset;
    private final long millisFromEpochToFiscalYearStart;
    private final long millisElapsedToEpochDividedByTwo;

    /**
     * Restricted constructor
     * @param fiscalYear
     * @param startingOn
     * @param inFirstWeek
     */
    protected SimpleFiscalYearEndPattern(final int fiscalYear, final LocalDate startingOn, final MonthDay inFirstWeek) {
        this.yearOffset = fiscalYear - startingOn.getYear();
        this.doomsdayOffset = getDoomsdayOffset(inFirstWeek);
        this.startingDayOfWeek = startingOn.getDayOfWeek();

        final int startingDoomsday = getDoomsdayOffset(new MonthDay(startingOn, REFERENCE_CHRONOLOGY));
        // If the starting doomsday is a later day-of-week, it needs to become negative.
        this.leapYearCountOffset = calculateLeapYearCountOffset(startingDoomsday : doomsdayOffset, doomsdayOffset);

        final int leapYearsBefore = getPreviousLeapYears(fiscalYearBeforeEpoch);
    }
}
```

(pared down) concrete class (for dates in range 1/7 - 2/28):

```
private static final class BeforeLeapYearEndPattern extends SimpleFiscalYearEndPattern {

    private static final int FIRST_YEAR_LEAP_YEAR_OFFSET = -1;

    private BeforeLeapYearEndPattern(final int fiscalYear, final LocalDate startingOn, final MonthDay onOrBefore) {
        super(fiscalYear, startingOn, onOrBefore);
    }

    public static final BeforeLeapYearEndPattern create(final int fiscalYear, final LocalDate startingOn, final MonthDay onOrBefore) {
        return new BeforeLeapYearEndPattern(fiscalYear, startingOn, onOrBefore);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see ext.site.time.chrono.FiscalYearEndPatternBuilder.SimpleFiscalYearEndPattern#getPreviousLeapYears(int)
     */
    @Override
    protected int getPreviousLeapYears(final int isoYear) {
        // Formula gets count of leap years, including current, so subtract a year first.
        final int previousYear = isoYear - 1;
        // If the doomsday offset is -1, then the first year is a leap year.
        return (previousYear + leapYearCountOffset + (previousYear / 4) - (previousYear / 100) + (previousYear / 400)) / 7 + (leapYearCountOffset == FIRST_YEAR_LEAP_YEAR_OFFSET ? 1 : 0);
    }
```

If you'll notice, I use `leapYearCountOffset`, which is defined (As a final variable) in the abstract super class, in `getPreviousLeapYears()`, which is then called from the super-class constructor.  I don't want to repeat the formula in the super-class constructor - it's different for dates in the range 3/1-12/31; nor do I want to place the instance variable in the concrete subclass - the other calculation still needs `leapYearCountOffset`.

**The Question Is:** What is the state of `leapYearCountOffset` at the time the (subclass) method is called from the constructor?  Is it guaranteed in any way, or is that something that could change at the whim of the compiler?  And how the heck could I test that to find out?  I'm already aware that the compiler is free to re-arrange some statements, but would (could?) that happen here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `getPreviousLeapYears` is called after `leapYearCountOffset` is assigned, `leapYearCountOffset` will be properly initialized and `getPreviousLeapYears` will see the correct value.

---

Java leaves the burden of ensuring that `final` variables that are accessed by code called during the constructor are properly initialized before first access.  If not properly initialized, code called during the constructor will see the zero value for that field's type.

The program

```
public class Foo {
  protected final int x;
  Foo() {
    foo();
    this.x = 1;
    foo();
  }
  void foo() { System.out.println(this.x); }
  public static void main(String[] argv) { new Foo(); }
}
```

prints

```
0
1
```

since `x` is not initialized during the first call to `foo`, but as explained above, you don't have this problem.

---

The JLS says that every use of a final *in the constructor* must be after initialization but makes no such guarantee for other methods. Consider

```
abstract class C {
  public final int x;

  C() {
    this.x = f();
  }

  abstract int f();
}
```

For the language to ensure that `x` is initialized before every use, it would need to ensure that no subclass exists like

```
class D extends C {
  int f() {
    return this.x;
  }
}
```

This requires global reasoning about classes which would be at odds with Java's dynamic linking and add a lot of complexity to the language specification.

Comment: But isn't the (implementation dependent) compiler allowed to re-arrange assignments, for performance considerations?  So, is my ordering guaranteed to be evaluated in that order (is it 'smart' enough to catch what I want)?  Or could I end up with `0` instead?

Comment: @X-Zero, The compiler is only allowed to do re-arrangements that do not change program semantics.

Comment: Ah, so I should be good then.  Although @Joni's concerns bear thinking about too.

Comment: @X-Zero, yes.  This code might be less maintainable than other code.  One way to address that, if you know that `leapYearsCountOffset` should never be zero is to `throw new IllegalStateException` if it is zero in `getPreviousLeapYears`.  If not, it may be worth redefining the meanings of fields so that the initialized value is never the zero-value for their type.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: I know, I'm late to the party but why exactly is access to a blank uninitialized final allowed via `this.x`? This behavior is not restricted to executed methods; you can access x in the constructor that way too. Using the simple name `x` however results in a compile time error. This goes against everything the JLS says (at least for the life of mine I can't find an explanation in the spec). It says repeatedly that every final must be *definitely assigned* before use.

Comment: @musiKk, The JLS says that every use of a final *in the constructor* must be after initialization but makes no such guarantee for other methods.  Consider `abstract class C { public final int x; C() { this.x = f(); } abstract int f(); }`.  For the language to ensure that `x` is initialized before every use, it would need to ensure that no subclass exists like `class D extends C { int f() { return this.x; } }`.  This requires global reasoning about classes which would be at odds with Java's dynamic linking and add a lot of complexity to the language specification.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Access to a *private* final variable in the constructor via `this.x` works too (but not via `x`)—before an assignment took place. I cannot wrap my head around this. I read a lot in the JLS about definite assignment (§16, it is actually fairly complex) but found no "hole" that would allow such behavior.

Comment: @musiKk, I don't see anything in my answer that suggests that `this.x` is any different from `x` provided that there is not a local variable or formal parameter named `x` that masks the member of the same name.  Can you be more specific about the code in this question that is confusing you?

Comment: @MikeSamuel this will sound like a cliche, but after so much reading about the guarantees that final will provide, this example and comments are the best here on SO. Thank you!

Comment: @Eugene, You're welcome.  I pulled an example from the comments into the answer which helps explain the choices facing the language designers.

Answer (score 4):

One of the guarantees of `final` variables is that the compiler won't let you access them before they're assigned.  So, if it compiles (which it should), you're good to go!

Comment: Not true with method calls.  Please see my answer for a program that demonstrates why.

Answer (score 0):

While `leapYearCountOffset` is guaranteed to have its final value, this is still an accident waiting to happen. The method `getPreviousLeapYears` is executed before the subclass initialization has started, so any variables from the subclass will have their default values (0 or null).

Right now there is no danger, but if someone comes in and changes `BeforeLeapYearEndPattern`, maybe by adding a new `final` instance variable, which is then used in `getPreviousLeapYears`, you will get hurt.

Comment: So, what, use anonymous methods, passed into the super-class constructor (or similar)?  What I wouldn't give to be able to use functions as first-class objects, now.

Comment: A common solution is refactoring things so that the subclass method is called lazily when the value is actually needed. Closures are not needed, though they could help.

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to need to tweak what I'm doing, I think.  While lazy-loading would be nice, I need that value pretty much right off, so...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this question is caused by confusion between intrathread and interthread semantics.

As long as you run the code in question in a single thread everything works as you would expect: there can be no visible effects of code reordering.

The same is true for `final` fields. `final` fields provide additional guarantees for concurrent access, and these guarantees only take effect after completion of constructors. That's why it's not recommended to make `final` fields accessible to other threads before completion of constructor. But it doesn't matter as long as you don't try to access the field in question from other threads.

However, I agree that calling subclass methods from constuctor of a superclass is a bad practice because subclass fields are not initialized at that point.

Comment: What? The base class part should get initialized before the derived class.